# How do I get a property from parent object for use as Map key?

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this

```
type IProperty<Type> = {
    [index: string]: Type
} & { name: string }

const testProp: IProperty<string> = {
  name: 'credential',
  valid: 'ABC',
  invalid: '123',
}
```

I would like to do something like this

```
class Actor {
    private props = new Map<string, unknown>()

    give(prop: unknown) {
        this.props.set(prop.name, prop) // Can't get prop.name here
    }

    get(prop: IProperty<unknown>): unknown {
        const value = this.props.get(prop.name)
        if (value !== undefined) return value
        else throw new Error(`Actor does not have ${prop.name}`)
    }
}

const actor = new Actor()

actor.give(testProp.valid)
console.log(actor.get(testProp)) // expecting 'ABC'

actor.give(testProp.invalid)
console.log(actor.get(testProp)) // expecting '123'
```

The problem is that the parameter for actor.get() does not have a 'name' property. That property exists on the parent object. I suspect I may be able to use [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to pass that property down to other properties on the object without having to do something this

```
// don't want to repeat name on all properties since it will be the same
const testProp: IProperty<string> = {
  valid: {name: 'credential', value: 'ABC'},
  invalid: {name: 'credential', value: '123'},
}
```

In my actor.give() function, is there a way to grab the name property to use as a key in the Map held by actor without duplicating it for each property in testProp?

Comment: You mean like: `actor.give(testProp[key])`

Comment: Correct, though I'd prefer to use dot notation for passing in the parameter

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking or trying to do.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that we can paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Right now `actor` isn't defined so I don't know what it does.  Presumably it is impossible to write `actor.give(testProp.valid)` and have `actor.give()` divine that it came from `testProp`; you'd have to actually pass it `testProp`, say by `actor.give(testProp, "valid")` or something.  But without a [mre] I'm just guessing.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: *"// Can't get prop.name here"* - Because you're passing it the string value `'ABC'` here: `actor.give(testProp.valid)`  If you want to get the `name` property of what you pass it, you have to pass it something with a `name` property, for example: `actor.give(testProp)`

Comment: So, as I said, you'll need to do `actor.give(testProp, "valid")` or something, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBJp4N) (I dumped `any` in there because your types are ‍♂️).  Does that meet your needs?  If so someone can write up an answer; if not, well, I don't see an alternative; values don't hold references to objects which might have them as properties

Comment: I was hoping to avoid specifying the key as a separate parameter in actor.give() but perhaps a helper function could work to create objects given a key and an object of value options like this: ```const testProp = Property<string>('credential', {valid: 'ABC', invalid: '123'})```